# Очень странно сохраняет фото на SD карту

Tags: java, android, камера

Я сохраняю фото с моего приложения в массив Bitmap. Далее когда я сделал необходимые мне снимки я вызываю функцию `saveAll()` как показано в коде ниже

```
public void saveAll(View view) {

    for (Bitmap b : arrBitmap) {
        SystemClock.sleep(1000);
        try {
            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
            if (pictureFile == null) {
                return;
            }
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(convertBitmapToByteArray(b));
            fos.close();

            Toast.makeText(context, "Picture saved: " + pictureFile.getName(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

}

private byte[] convertBitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bitmap.getWidth() *
            bitmap.getHeight());
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}

private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
    File mediaStorageDir = new File("/sdcard/", "JCG Camera");

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" +
            timeStamp + ".jpg");

    return mediaFile;
}
```

и фото сохраняется очень странно, во первых может вообще не сохраниться или сохраниться все кроме первой или сначала не сохраниться, но потом когда я далее тестирую код они могут появиться... хотя каждый раз показывает `Toast` что все сохраняется... скажите пожалуйста

что я делаю не так?

Comment: можете показать что выводит `Exception e` ?

Comment: Так он ничего не выводит, показывает, что функция полностью отрабатывает...

Answer (score 1):

Вы как-то слишком усложняете свое сохранение Bitmap в файл. Это делается очень просто:

```
FileOutputStream out = null;
try { 
    out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
    // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored 
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally { 
    try { 
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        } 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Я думаю, что проблемы именно из за усложнения.
Кроме того, работая с большим кол-вом `Bitmap`'ов вы рискуете поймать `OOM`

Comment: В вашем примере показано, что не нужно переводить обратно из Bitmap в byte[]. И write() тоже не нужно? Насколько я понимаю мы создаем место для сохранения, потом создаем файл который будем сохранять и мы должны в этот файл записать наши байты? так?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, место для записи файла предварительно не создается. `Bitmap.compress()` запишет изображение в выбранном формате и с выбранным сжатием в любой ` OutputStream`. В данном случае `FileOutputStream`